# pass array between 2 activity with intent

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent

i'm trying to pass one array

[the array is inizialized by me {1,2,3,4} and i associate the string "txx"]

between two activity but i recive this error

```
java.lang.runtimeexception: unable to start activity  
componentinfo{com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.graphcurrentactivity}: 
java.lang.nullpointerexception: attempt to read from null array
```

from debug mode i see that this array doesn't pass between two activity. i think that there can be an error in delcaration private/public variable..

please help me

activity A

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;


private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA2 =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA2";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA3 =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA3";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA4 =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA4";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA5 =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA5";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA6 =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA6";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA7 =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA7";

byte[] value;
int[] data_info = new int[6];
public int[] grap_curr = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
public int[] grap_volt = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
public int[] grap_temp = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
public int[] grap_soc = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
public int[] grap_soh = new int[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;


public final static UUID UUID_USER_DATA =
        UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.FIRST_NAME);
public ArrayList<String> receivedPackets = new ArrayList<String>();
// Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
// connection change and services discovered.
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
  final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    /* Creo le Intent per passare i dati da visualizzare sui grafici alle altre classi */
    Intent intentCurr = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GraphCurrentActivity.class);
    //final Intent intentVolt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GraphVoltageActivity.class);
    //final Intent intentTemp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GraphTempActivity.class);
    //final Intent intentSoC = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GraphSoCActivity.class);
   //final Intent intentSoH = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GraphSoHActivity.class);

    if (UUID_USER_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Value format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Value format UINT8.");
        }

            value = characteristic.getValue();
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
            bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

            i++;


        if (value != null && value.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(value.length);
                for(byte byteChar : value)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));

            //su value ho la stringa ricevuta, quindi posso elaborare il dato per far si che leggo sulla app quello che voglio

            Byte b5 = value[5];
            Byte b6 = value[6];
            Byte b7 = value[7];

            data_info[0] = ((value[1] << 8) | (value [2] & 0xFF));//current
            data_info[1] = ((value[3] << 8) | (value [4] & 0xFF));//voltage
            data_info[2] = b5.intValue();//soc
            data_info[3] = b6.intValue();//temp
            data_info[4] = b7.intValue();//soh
            data_info[5] = ((value[8] << 8) | (value [9] & 0xFF));

            //preparo i dati da passare alle alre activity
            grap_curr[j]=data_info[2];
            grap_volt[j]=data_info[2];
            grap_temp[j]=data_info[2];
            grap_soc[j]=data_info[2];
            grap_soh[j]=data_info[2];
            j++;

            //dopo 10 cicli invio ai grafici
            if (j==3){
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA7, "Riepilogo temporale disponibile");
                Bundle curr =new  Bundle (); //array da mandare alla activity GraphCurrentActivity
                curr.putIntArray("txxx",new int[] {1,2,3,4});
                intentCurr.putExtras(curr);
                //intentCurr.putExtra("tx",grap_curr);
                //intentCurr.putExtra("datavectorcurr",new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
                //intentVolt.putExtra("datavectorvolt",new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
                //intentTemp.putExtra("datavectortemp",new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
                //intentSoC.putExtra("datavectorsoc",new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
                //intentSoH.putExtra("datavectorsoh",new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});
                j=0;
            }

            //inserisco i dati negli appositi campi
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA,  "Battery Current: " + Integer.toString(data_info[0]) + " [A]" );
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA2, "Battery Voltage: " + Integer.toString(data_info[1]) + " [V]" );
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA3, "SOC: " + Integer.toString(data_info[2]) + " [Ah]" );
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA4, "SOH: " + Integer.toString(data_info[4]) + " [%]");
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA5, "average temperature: " + Integer.toString(data_info[3]) + " [°C]");
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA6, "remaining capacity: " + Integer.toString(data_info[5]) + " [°Ah]");

        }

    }

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    BluetoothLeService getService() {
        return BluetoothLeService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
    // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
    // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
    close();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

/**
 * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
 *
 * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
 */
public boolean initialize() {
    // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
    // BluetoothManager.
    if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
 *
 * @param address The device address of the destination device.
 *
 * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
 *         is reported asynchronously through the
 *         {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 *         callback.
 */
public boolean connect(final String address) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        return false;
    }

    // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
    if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
            && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
        if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
        return false;
    }
    // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
    // parameter to false.
    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
    mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
 * is reported asynchronously through the
 * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
 * callback.
 */
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
}

/**
 * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
 * released properly.
 */
public void close() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.close();
    mBluetoothGatt = null;
}

/**
 * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
 * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
 * callback.
 *
 * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
 */
public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
}

/**
 * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
 *
 * @param characteristic Characteristic to act on.
 * @param enabled If true, enable notification.  False otherwise.
 */
public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                          boolean enabled) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

    // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
    if (UUID_USER_DATA.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This should be
 * invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()} completes successfully.
 *
 * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
 */
public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

    return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
}

public void readCustomCharacteristic() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000181c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if(mCustomService == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
        return;
    }


    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mNotifyCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a8a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = mNotifyCharacteristic.getDescriptor(uuid);
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    //To receive notification in Android is mandatory to set characteristic notification to true
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, true);

    /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002A8A-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
    if(mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic) == false){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read characteristic");
    }
}

public void writeCustomCharacteristic(int value) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000181c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if(mCustomService == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
        return;
    }
    /*get the write characteristic from the service*/
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a8a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(value,android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8,0);
    if(mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic) == false){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
    }
}
```

}

activty B

```
public class GraphCurrentActivity extends Activity {

private XYPlot plot;
private GoogleApiClient client;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    // initialize our XYPlot reference:
    plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.plot);

    Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int[] arraydata;
    arraydata = b.getIntArray("txxx");//array that i don't recive


    // create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
    final Number[] domainLabels = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    //Number[] series1Numbers = {plottdata[0], plottdata[1], plottdata[2], plottdata[3], plottdata[4], plottdata[5], plottdata[6], plottdata[7], plottdata[8], plottdata[9]};
    Number[] series1Numbers = {11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 5, 8, 7, 1, 11};
    // turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    // (Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value)
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(series1Numbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Battery Current Plot");

    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);


    series1Format.setInterpolationParams(
            new CatmullRomInterpolator.Params(10, CatmullRomInterpolator.Type.Centripetal));


    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM).setFormat(new Format() {
        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
            int i = Math.round(((Number) obj).floatValue());
            return toAppendTo.append(domainLabels[i]);
        }

        @Override
        public Object parseObject(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
            return null;
        }
    });
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}

public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("GraphCurrent Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();
}
}
```

Comment: it also give me this error on 

arraydata = b.getIntArray("txxx");//array that i don't recive

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.GraphCurrentActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int[] android.os.Bundle.getIntArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution I can suggest is define your array as

```
public static int[] xyz=new int[]{1,2,3,4};
```

And now that static int array can be called or used from any activity provided if they are in the same package. 
Here for your example in GraphCurrentActivity,
Add this import statement:

```
import static yourpackagename.BluetoothLeService.xyz;

//And these lines to read that array:
int[] arraydata;
    arraydata = xyz;
```

And let me know if this was wrong.

Comment: so without an intent?